# Using Google Sheets to create a .xslx file from sql data

Tags: angularjs, node.js, excel, google-sheets-api, hebrew

I am trying to create a `.xlsx` file with data I retrieve from `mysql` to a `node.js` server that serves an `angularjs` project, but after hours of trying to find something via `npm` or `google` I almost gave up!

The two main problems I have are:

- My data is in hebrew (i.e. rtl styling + different characters).
- The Excel file that I export needs to be styled in a specific way, and it is a pain trying to style an excel file grammatically.

And then I had an idea!

What if I could create a `google sheet` doc in my google drive as a template including the styling, and then when the user clicks to create a new doc, I would just duplicate this template, and change the values to the new data.

But just trying to understand the `google api` is a headache on its on, apparently, there are 3! different api's: Drive, Sheets and auth.

So my question is as follows.

- Is my idea valid? does anyone think it could work?
- Where would I start, is there some guide or npm that would help?

Please don't comment to look in the docs, I am having a hard time to understand where to start from there.

Comment: First off [OAuth is not an API](https://stormpath.com/blog/what-the-heck-is-oauth). Then, you'll have to find a way to connect your SQL to your spreadsheet, and I think [Apps Script can help in that regard](https://ctrlq.org/code/19978-connect-to-google-cloud-sql-from-apps-script), this [SO post is also related](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42906/google-spreadsheet-connect-with-database-and-fetch-data-to-cells). With regard to your template, you're going to have to replace the dummy data in your spreadsheet template with the real ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating the template file locally instead of opting to google spreads.
There is a decent module I used sometime back, which does styling pretty well, Its called [exceljs](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs).
Though there is always the [xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) module, Which is very powerful but difficult to use

Also if you end up using google spreadsheets, I would suggest giving [node-google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet) module a look

Comment: The exceljs library looks very promising, I will try it. Any idea where to save the files if not in Google drive account?

Comment: You can save it in the backend, where the  Nodejs server is running from.

Comment: but that means that every time I update the application all the files will be deleted, is there any other free hosting where I can save the files?

Comment: There is nothing as free, though you could use box or Dropbox.
You can even put it up on GitHub or gitlab. If it's not something confidential then GitHub should fit best

Comment: Also can u not store the files somewhere on the same box, 
Not along the code. So it won't get deleted when u refresh